# Logging out of chat is counter-intuitive

Tags: bug, logout

Chat does not provide its own log-out button, nor is it obvious from any of the main menus. Eventually, I was able to figure out that if I logged out of chat by going to chat.<whatever>/logout *and* logged out of the main site (two separate steps) it let me log as someone else other than the person logged in. This presents two major problems:

1. Logging out should be obvious from at least one of the menus. (Just like it is on the non-chat sites)
2. Logging out should be complete — auto-login should not work until someone else logs in. Since it kept storing my credentials after I initially logged out, this represents what should be seen as a significant security risk.

I listed this as bug because, frankly, this is beyond an ***epic UI fail***. The system fundamentally does not work as expected in a very important way.

---

Steps followed:

1. Go to chat site.
2. Found that I was logged in as account 1
3. Where is logout? (bug 1)
4. Go to stackexchange.com (***apparently already signed in as account 2***. This might be a secondary bug: I was logged in to chat as one account, and stackexchange as another)
5. Log out of stackexchange.com
6. Apparently I was still logged in to chat! ***(!!!)***
7. Find chat logout after searching meta site.
8. Logged out of chat.
9. Auto login still let me log in ***(!!!)***
10. Logged out of chat again
11. Logged in to stackexchange under account 2
12. Logged in to chat as account 2.

Comment: To clarify - you're saying that if you log out of Stack Exchange (through one of the sites) you're still logged in on chat? That does seem like a bug...